# Ditching most of the Oraclize API

Tags: oracles

The Oraclize API has a bunch of methods that my contract doesn't use. I was going to delete a bunch of them to save on gas costs for deployment. Are there any other considerations I should be aware of? Couldn't find this practice recommended in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you're going to delete some methods in an interface you're consuming, there should be no harm, but I don't believe you'll see any gas savings. Interfaces you use shouldn't end up in the code you deploy in your contract.

Comment: The compiler figures out which functions your contract uses, so deleting unused API functions doesn't matter.

Comment: That may be true, but interfaces shouldn't end up in the code at all ("used" or "unused"), because they're needed at compile time but aren't needed at all at runtime.